# What is the WEBGL version/level required for the smaa post-processing example?

Tags: three.js, antialiasing

The [SMAA post-processing example](https://threejs.org/examples/webgl_postprocessing_smaa.html) is by far the best antialiasing method in my tests, but it's **extremely complex** and I'm worried  that most-likely it's not WEBGL-1.0, so it won't run on older PCs and devices at all.
Anyone knows what version is it?

And what is the actual load on GPU, is there a tool to inspect the milliseconds per frame? Relying just on dropped framerate is next to useless.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the `SMAAPass` with WebGL 1. WebGL 2 is not even supported by `three.js`. Looking at the respective shader code, I would say it should also compile on older hardware.

I don't have any concrete performance measurements but I can guarantee that this pass will add noticeable overhead to your application, especially on mobile devices.

`three.js R92`